# bigintcalc: using a result in further calculations

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, tikzmath, bigintcalc

I have a `\newcommand` that calcs 
[image]
for predefined variables
[image]

Hint: I use `bigintcalc.sty` for huge numbers; and `pgfmath` to define variables (and maybe other calculations).

I would like to have the result as a **macro**, like `\Prod{3}`, such that I can do further calculations; for example `\Prod{3}+1`.

But this might not to work, if I put \Prod{3} in another `\bigintcalc`, e.g. `\bigintcalcAdd{1}{\Prod{3}}`.

What do I have to do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}% for numbered Variables \x{1}, \x{2}, .... 
\usepackage{bigintcalc}% for big numbers  (e.g. 9^66)

\begin{document}
\section*{Define Variables}
\tikzmath{
int \i;
\i=0;
for \xValue in {2, 3, 7, 42, 1806}{%
      \i=\numexpr\i+1\relax;
      \x{\i}=\xValue;  
};%  %%
}

x(1)= \x{1}, ~~~  x(2)= \x{2}, ~~~  x(3)= \x{3}, ~~~  x(4)= \x{4}, ~~~  x(5)= \x{5}


\section*{bigintcalc-Product as command -- works}
\newcommand\Prod[1]{%
\def\N{#1}%
\def\p{1}%
 \foreach \k in {1,...,\N}{%%
  \xdef\p{\bigintcalcMul{\p}{\x{\k}}}%
}%%
\p}%

$\text{Prod(3)} =  \Prod{3} 
  = x(1) \times x(2) \times x(3) = 2 \times 3 \times 7$


\section*{Using the result for other calculations-- works not}
\text{Prod(3)} + 1 = %\bigintcalcAdd{1}{\Prod{3}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your macro `\Prod` is defined to store the result in the macro `\p`. So the result of `\Prod` is accessible within other calculations as `\p`.

Alternatively you can define a fully expandable macro-mechanism
`\MyProd{⟨array-macro⟩}{⟨lowest array index⟩}{⟨highest array index⟩}`
which delivers the result of the calculation by triggering two expansion-steps. Expansion could be done via `\expanded{..}`/`\expanded{\unexpanded{..}..}`, but with the following example I decided to use `\romannumeral` for triggering expansion.

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}% for numbered Variables \x{1}, \x{2}, .... 
\usepackage{bigintcalc}% for big numbers  (e.g. 9^66)

\newcommand\Prod[1]{%
  \def\p{1}%
  \foreach \k in {1,...,#1}{%
    \xdef\p{\bigintcalcMul{\p}{\x{\k}}}%
  }%
  \p
}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\@ifdefinable\stopromannumeral{\chardef\stopromannumeral`\^^00 }%
\newcommand\MyProd[3]{%
  % #1 - array-macro; #2 - lowest array index;  #3 - highest array index; 
  \romannumeral
  \expandafter\MyProdLoop
  \expandafter{\the\numexpr(#3)\relax}{#1}{1}{#2}{}%
}%
\newcommand\MyProdLoop[5]{%
  % #1 - highest array index; #2 - array-macro; #3 - 1 or empty ; 
  % #4 - current array index;  #5 - result currently calculated so far; 
  \ifnum\numexpr(#4)\relax>\numexpr(#1)\relax
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi
  {%
    % manual of bigintcalc says: "The macros are fully expandable,
    % exactly two expansion steps generate the result."
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\PassFirstToSecond
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \bigintcalcMul{#3#5}{#2{#4}}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
        \the\numexpr(#4)+1\relax
      }{%
        \MyProdLoop{#1}{#2}{}%
      }%
    }%
  }{\stopromannumeral#5}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section*{Define Variables}
\tikzmath{%
  int \i;
  \i=0;
  for \xValue in {2, 3, 7, 42, 1806}{%
    \i=\numexpr\i+1\relax;
    \x{\i}=\xValue;  
  };%
}%
\(x(1) = \x{1}\), \hfill
\(x(2) = \x{2}\), \hfill
\(x(3) = \x{3}\), \hfill
\(x(4) = \x{4}\), \hfill
\(x(5) = \x{5}\)%

\section*{bigintcalc-Product as command -- works}

\(\text{Prod(3)} =  \Prod{3} = \p = x(1) \times x(2) \times x(3) = 2 \times 3 \times 7\)

\section*{Using the result stored as \texttt{\string\p} for other calculations}
% The result of \Prod{3} is in \p, so use \p:
\(\text{Prod(3)} + 1 = \bigintcalcAdd{1}{\p}\)

\section*{Expandably calculating the result within other calculations by means of \texttt{\string\MyProd}}
% Use the expandable variant:
\(\text{Prod(3)} + 1 = \bigintcalcAdd{1}{\MyProd{\x}{1}{3}}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case a TeX engine is in use where `\unexpanded` and `\expanded` are available, you can define `\MyProd`, e.g., as follows:

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand\MyProd[3]{%
  % #1 - array-macro; #2 - lowest array index;  #3 - highest array index; 
  \expanded{\expandafter\MyProdLoop\expandafter{\the\numexpr(#3)\relax}{#1}{1}{#2}{}}%
}%
\newcommand\MyProdLoop[5]{%
  % #1 - highest array index; #2 - array-macro; #3 - 1 or empty ; 
  % #4 - current array index;  #5 - result currently calculated so far; 
  \ifnum\numexpr(#4)\relax>\numexpr(#1)\relax
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi
  {%
    \expanded{%
      \unexpanded{\MyProdLoop{#1}{#2}}{}{\the\numexpr(#4)+1\relax}{\bigintcalcMul{#3#5}{#2{#4}}}%
    }%
  }{\unexpanded{#5}}%
}
\makeatother
```

---

If you are bold enough

- both to use a LaTeX distribution recent enough to come along with l3kernel package [2021‑05‑07] or later, where `\clist_map_tokens:nn` is available
- and to trust that the l3kernel-internal implementation of  `\clist_map_tokens:nn` won't change anytime soon,

then you can implement an expandable macro `\ArrayElementProduct` where exactly two expansion steps generate the result, which as its arguments takes the array-macro-token and a comma-separated list of array indices and via `\clist_map_tokens:nn` iterates the comma-list, to each comma-list-item applying a macro which multiplies the array-element whose index-number is denoted by the comma-list item with the result gathered so far, whereby the result gathered so far is maintained by in each iteration hooking into `\clist_map_tokens:nn`'s internal breaking of mapping:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}% for numbered Variables \x{1}, \x{2}, .... 
\usepackage{bigintcalc}% for big numbers  (e.g. 9^66)

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \ArrayElementProduct #1#2 {
  \exp:w
  \exp_last_unbraced:No
  \MyStuff_arrayelementproduct_hook_in_clist_mapbreak_initial:wn
  {
    \clist_map_tokens:nn {#2}{ \MyStuff_arrayelementproduct_hook_in_clist_mapbreak:nnwn{#1} }
  }
}
\cs_new:Npn \MyStuff_arrayelementproduct_hook_in_clist_mapbreak_initial:wn #1 \prg_break_point:Nn \clist_map_break: #2 {
  #1 \prg_break_point:Nn \clist_map_break: { \exp_end: }
}
\cs_new:Npn \MyStuff_arrayelementproduct_hook_in_clist_mapbreak:nnwn #1#2#3 \prg_break_point:Nn \clist_map_break: #4 {
  \exp_args:Nne \use:n { #3 \prg_break_point:Nn \clist_map_break:} {
    \tl_if_empty:oTF{\use_none:n #4} {
      \exp_not:n {\exp_end:} \bigintcalcMul{1}
    }{
      \exp_not:n {\exp_end:} \bigintcalcMul{\use_none:n #4}
    }{#1{#2}} 
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section*{Define Variables}
\tikzmath{%
  int \i;
  \i=0;
  for \xValue in {2, 3, 7, 42, 1806}{%
    \i=\numexpr\i+1\relax;
    \x{\i}=\xValue;  
  };%
}%
\(x(1) = \x{1}\), \hfill
\(x(2) = \x{2}\), \hfill
\(x(3) = \x{3}\), \hfill
\(x(4) = \x{4}\), \hfill
\(x(5) = \x{5}\)%

\section*{Multiply Variables}
\(x(1) \times x(3) \times x(5) = \x{1} \times \x{3} \times \x{5} = \ArrayElementProduct{\x}{1, 3 , 5}\)

\section*{Test edge cases of input}

\verb*|(\ArrayElementProduct{\x}{1, 3 ,,, , 5})|: (\ArrayElementProduct{\x}{1, 3 ,,, , 5})

\noindent
\verb*|(\ArrayElementProduct{\x}{4})|: (\ArrayElementProduct{\x}{4})

\noindent
\verb*|(\ArrayElementProduct{\x}{,  ,,, , })|: (\ArrayElementProduct{\x}{,  ,,, , })

\noindent
\verb*|(\ArrayElementProduct{\x}{,})|: (\ArrayElementProduct{\x}{,})

\noindent
\verb*|(\ArrayElementProduct{\x}{})|: (\ArrayElementProduct{\x}{})

\noindent
\verb*|(\ArrayElementProduct{\x}{ })|: (\ArrayElementProduct{\x}{ })

\end{document}
```

[image]

(I wonder if I overlooked an official interface for this kind of things.)

Comment: The look of the last example seems to indicate that TeX -LaTeX Stack Exchange's syntax-highlighting currently can be confused by `\verb|...|`.